# Is there a way to load a text string first and then the image using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to parse JSON to my app (using Rails as my backend). Right now my app is very slow so I'm trying to figure out a way to make it smoother. When I first load the app it takes a few seconds for it to populate (it shows the Nav items and a white page, then a few seconds later my "posts" appear).

**Collection View Controller**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.upcomingReleases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self makeReleasesRequests];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ReleaseCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReleaseCell"];
}

-(void)makeReleasesRequests
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.soleresource.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"@");

        self.upcomingReleases = [responseObject objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    } failure:nil];

    [operation start];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.upcomingReleases count];
}

#pragma mark - Show upcoming release shoe

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    ReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *thumbURL = nil;

    cell.release_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ — $%@",[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"], [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_price"]];

    if ([upcomingReleaseDictionary[@"images"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [upcomingReleaseDictionary[@"images"] count]) {
        thumbURL = upcomingReleaseDictionary[@"images"][0][@"image_file"][@"image_file"][@"thumb"][@"url"];
        if (thumbURL)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            cell.thumb.image = image;
        }
    }
    else {
        cell.thumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"air-jordan-5-fear.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Each of my posts has a text string and a image. Is there a way to load the text so that it appears right away and then load my image? Or is there another way to speed up my app load speed (Maybe loadin a certain of posts first and then loading the rest - the ones that the user cant see until they scroll down).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load your image lazily and asynchronously (DON'T block main thread) when coming from server. (AFNetworking already has caching category method on UIImageView. (Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730138/uiimageviewafnetworking-setimagewithurl-with-animation) for more)

```
    if (thumbURL)
    {
        [cell.thumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"air-jordan-5-fear.png"]];
    }
```

**EDIT** -

Ensure to pull *UIKit+AFNetworking* folder into your project and `#import "UIKit+AFNetworking.h"` into your .m file. The link to download complete AFNetworking can be found [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and documentation specific to this question [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html).

Comment: This code is bad because when the image is finished loading, the cell may have been reused to show different data.  I am certain with this code, if you scroll very quickly, you will start to see images load on the wrong cells.

Comment: ChrisBedoya - Can you please verify what Aaron said? I suspect he might be right and this (alternative approach) can be a potentially wrong way to in reusable cells. Pls let me know if so, I would remove the alternative solution from my answer. Thanks @AaronBrager for raising this.

Comment: Removed the alternative method. In fact, AFNetworking itself has caching UIImageView category method so the above answer should be pretty straight forward now.

Comment: I get this error: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:'. I'm using Collection View Controller just in case that helps.

Comment: In that case, you downloaded AFNetworking files from a different fork and not from this - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: I had AFNetworking, I needed to add "UIKit+AFNetworking.h" and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to know that you got it working, finally. CONGRATS. I would edit my answer to benefit others who later visit this. Please do consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
    if (thumbURL)
    {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        cell.thumb.image = image;
    }
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

You should never be *getting data* in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.  You should only be displaying what you have already.  Your code makes it so no cell is returned until a thumbnail is downloaded.  You can measure this using the *Time Profiler* in Instruments.

I'm assuming `thumb` is a UIImageView.  Try this:

```
if (thumb) {
    [thumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"]];
}
```

This method, also included with AFNetworking, will download the image, and update it in the cell once it's done downloading.  [Documentation and other similar methods are here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html).

Comment: The first approach is synchronous; the one I recommended is asynchronous.  Read more about the difference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: What do I have to change in my code so that is loads the images asynchronous?

Comment: Use the suggestion I provided.  Or, start downloading your image when the cell scrolls in, and then reload the row once the image is done.  The AFNetworking method was provided for exactly this purpose though.

Comment: I'm confused - you said in your question that you're already using AFNetworking.

Comment: If I change my "if (thumbURL)" code to your code, I get an error saying "undeclared use of thumb", if I change "thumb" to "thumbURL", I get an error saying "No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector setImageWithURL".

Comment: You need to `#import "UIKit+AFNetworking.h"`, and use `cell.thumb`.