# table view scrolling smooth with url images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have a table view that loads title and images from url address. Since I added the images, the scrolling isn't smooth. I have changed the background to clear. The images are low resolution. I prefer accessing them with url, not to downloaded the image and re-upload it on the app. Looking forward for your solutions to make the scrolling smooth. Thanks

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *str = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
[[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
[[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16.0]];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.TitleLabel.text=str;

UIImage *pImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feeds2[indexPath.row]]]];;
[cell.ThumbImage setImage:pImage];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: load image on background thread , not on main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

after this line `cell.TitleLabel.text=str;`

That way you load each image in the background and as soon as its loaded the corresponding cell is updated on the mainThread.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        NSData *imgData =  NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feeds2[indexPath.row]]];
        if (imgData) {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

           dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                      if (image) {
                           cell.ThumbImage.image = image;
             }
        });
    });
```

A better approach is to cache the image , so you dont need to download them each time , the table scroll.

here are some very good references to accomplish this.

[LazyTableImages Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

[UIImageView+AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730138/uiimageviewafnetworking-setimagewithurl-with-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simply you have to implement the loading with `NSOperation` where a custom class to handle your download and have your `NSOperationQueue` as `downloadQueue`. Every `UITableView` is a (sub class) `UIScrollView` therefore you can use the methods directly.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [downloadQueue cancelAllOperations]; // clear your queue
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    if (!decelerate) {
        // start download only for visible cells
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // start download only for visible cells
}
```

for more detail information visit [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) tutorial. There you can really find good solution for your need.