# How to download infinite number of images from remote server and display the images in UICollection View/UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks, uicollectionview

I want to display the infinite images in UITableView/UICollectionview, here the images will be received from remote server, I've done this by using GCD but it causes Memory issues and app got crash.Please help to fix it. Also I noticed some images aren't deallocated. Here is piece of code I've used to download images.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        if (image1.size.width != 130 || image1.size.height != 100)
            {
                CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(130, 100);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, 0.0f);
                CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                [image1 drawInRect:imageRect];
                image1  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                [self setImage:image1 forKey:[url absoluteString]];
                //  NSLog(@" down Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(image1);
            //image1=nil;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can work with: [AFNetworking+UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730138/uiimageviewafnetworking-setimagewithurl-with-animation)

About the memory issues and crashes, be careful with the retain cycles, use the profiler/Instruments, if you want to continue with your code is good idea to change:

```
__weak MyClassViewOrViewController* weakSelf = self;      
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    ...
    __strong MyClassViewOrViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf setImage:image1 forKey:[url absoluteString]];
    ...
});
```

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using LazyLoading Concept

Reference:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load infinite image, good performance, cache..